# How to treat data of one parameter measured with two same devices that show slight differences in averge

Tags: measurement

I have measured one parameter with two identical devices. Unfortunately one device shows higher values on average. Also maximum and minimum of the values differ by exactly the same value like the average. Can I just substract the mean difference from values measured with the device which measured slightly too high values. Or is there any statistical approach for this issue?

Comment: what are you aiming at? validating an instrument? check the two instruments give the same result?

Comment: Are they identical except for some offset i.e. is the difference constant? Also, can you say more about the instrument & data, and what you are trying to achieve?